# Rails: Fixture -- StandardError: No fixture with name 'abcd' found for table 'xyz'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures

On running my unit test i get the following error:

```
StandardError: No fixture with name 'abcd' found for table 'xyz'
```

I did make sure that a fixture named "abcd" is infact present in **test/fixtures/xyz.yml**

Content of my test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'action_view/test_case'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
 unless Test::Unit::TestCase.const_defined?('FIXTURE_CLASS_MAP')
    Test::Unit::TestCase::FIXTURE_CLASS_MAP = {
      :feedback_forms => Feedback::Form,
    }
  end

  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
  set_fixture_class FIXTURE_CLASS_MAP
end
```

Please help me understand why this error occurs.

UPDATE: I just figured out that, when running a test, the records in DB are deleted (for that table) and  the records in the fixture files are inserted into DB tables.
In my case, not all the records are INSERTed into the table (only the first record is inserted) - Any clue of why it could happen?

Thanks
Ramya

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but my guess would be that you did not specify the relevant model associations. The named fixture in your example will not work unless you've specified the following in `app/models/xyz.rb`:

```
class XYZ < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :abcd
end
```